# I don't understand the SharePoint permission system

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have created a site in SharePoint 365.  I am the owner.  I have full control.  Yet when I do specific actions (e.g., change the navigation settings) I am told that I must request access.  I do this and the request comes to me.  I approve myself to have access but nothing changes.  I am still unable to complete the action.  SharePoint still prompts me to request access.

Here are my permissions as originally set up by default with the site.

[image: Here are my permissions as originally set up by default with the site.]

[image]

Comment: Is this a Modern Team site?

Comment: Is this inside a corporate tenant of some sort? I work for a large organization and within our tenant certain features aren't enabled. I experienced something very similar to what you are describing if I tried to enable those features.

Comment: I am testing Modern and Classic.  This one happens to be my Classic site, but I see the same behavior in both.  Yes, this is a large corporate site.  This particular error instance is when I try to show subsite navigation in the site or site navigation in the subsites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you approve access via email it adds you to an existing group in that site(if the settings for that group is wrong Nothing will change

There are several ways to test this.
I would take the following action to see what is the issue.
From what I see you have put some exception on the group permission 
First Try to add yourself Directly to that Site
on your site Click Share>Share With>Advance
This will open the Permission setting for this site
now add yourself to directly to the site(from grant access)
Your Permission window should look like this
[image]

If this works It means The settings for the existing groups is wrong.

There is another possibility. There setting for Permission level might be wrong.
for this purpose Click Permission levels, then in the new page click on Full Control and edit the permission. this will solve the issue!

Comment: Thank you all.  I think this is a setting from the tenant admins.  Nothing I do seems to fix the problem.  I specifically assigned Full Control and I see that Limited Access is assigned by default and I can't change it.  See the screen clip I added to the question section above.

Comment: What you are seeing is the default behavior of the permissions structure.  I would advise you not to edit group permissions.  As with On Prem SharePoint, the best way to grant Permissions is through the Site Settings>Permissions setting rather than Sharing through Email.

Comment: @Richard did you try to give direct permission to yourself.  through site permission? It should do the job. the solution should work. I normally spend days defining permission levels and permission groups in O365 based on the customer need. in that case you will have correct categories in email.

Comment: Another suggestion is , as your question is about office 365, Sharepoint I strongly recommend you contact Microsoft and submit a ticket via the admin Portal. As we can not check your tenant but they can. they are so helpful and fast.